# GCP service Account Authentication

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-cloud-iam

I created a service account for a specific role by going through the steps mentioned here.

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys

after generating the keys in json file when i am trying to authenticate with credentials using gcloud using

gcloud auth activate-service-account ACCOUNT --key-file=KEY-FILE

ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) Unable to read file [#path of file#]: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'filename.json'

Comment: Can you show your folder structure? Seems that the file is not in the same directory where you execute the activation script.

If possible, print the output of `dir` in the same directory where you execute the gcloud command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your question the key file basically is the service account key file that we have downloaded and in the command gcloud auth activate-service-account ACCOUNT --key-file=KEY-FILE  we  need to give the path of the json keyfile .

I faced this same issue ,so I created the json keys through gcloud .

steps-

1. create the keys through gcloud command in cloud shell

**gcloud iam service-accounts keys create OUTPUT-FILE --iam-account=IAM_ACCOUNT [--key-file-type=KEY_FILE_TYPE; default="json"] [GCLOUD_WIDE_FLAG …]**

example-
**gcloud iam service-accounts keys create key.json  --iam-account=my-iam-account@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com**

2. after generating the keys  we need to give the command for the credential authentication

**gcloud auth activate-service-account ACCOUNT --key-file=KEY-FILE**

Give the service account email that you have created in Account and the key we generated using gcloud command

example-
**gcloud auth activate-service-account [service-account-name-]@[projectID].iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file=key.json**

i am attaching public docs links for reference.

[Authentication using Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication#gcloud-helper)

[service account key generate using gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/iam/service-accounts/keys/create)

Comment: this worked for me , not facing the error now. Thank you!!