# Error: denied: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" denied on resource

Tags: python, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-iam

I am new in [`Python`](https://www.python.org/). I am deploying [`Python`](https://www.python.org/) code to [`Google Cloud Run`](https://cloud.google.com/run) and I am getting an error.

Here is the terminal:

```
Deploying from source. To deploy a container use [--image]. See https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/deploying-source-code for more details.
Source code location (/Users/name/......):  
Next time, use `gcloud run deploy --source .` to deploy the current directory.

Service name (google-cloud-run):  
Please specify a region:
 [1] asia-east1
 ......
Please enter your numeric choice:  27

To make this the default region, run `gcloud config set run/region us-central1`.

This command is equivalent to running `gcloud builds submit --tag [IMAGE] /Users/name/......` and `gcloud run deploy google-cloud-run --image [IMAGE]`

Allow unauthenticated invocations to [google-cloud-run] (y/N)?  y

Building using Dockerfile and deploying container to Cloud Run service [google-cloud-run] in project [project-id] region [us-central1]
X Building and deploying new service... Building Container.                                                                                    
  ✓ Uploading sources...                                                                                                                       
  - Building Container... Logs are available at [https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds/bdaf9cea-3e87-46e4-81f8-33b2675808f8?proje
  ct=1044629281917].                                                                                                                           
  . Creating Revision...                                                                                                                       
  . Routing traffic...                                                                                                                         
  . Setting IAM Policy...                                                                                                                      
Deployment failed                                                                                                                              
ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) Build failed; check build logs for details
```

It ***looks*** like it fails in the build container.

When I check my logs, the error is: `denied: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" denied on resource "projects/project-id/locations/us-central1/repositories/cloud-run-source-deploy" (or it may not exist)`.

My code:

```
import os

from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    name = os.environ.get("NAME", "World")
    return "Hello {}!".format(name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get("PORT", 8080)))
```

My Google Cloud IAM account roles:

- Artifact Registry Administrator
- Artifact Registry Reader
- Artifact Registry Repository Administrator
- Artifact Registry Writer
- Cloud Build Editor
- Cloud Run Admin
- Container Registry Service Agent
- Service Account Admin
- Service Account User
- Service Usage Admin
- Service Usage Consumer
- Source Repository Administrator
- Source Repository Reader
- Source Repository Writer
- Storage Admin
- Storage Object Admin
- Viewer

How can I fix this error? Appreciate if someone can advise. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This [Quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-python-service#before-you-begin) explains how to deploy a Python service on Cloud run.

As mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-python-service#deploy) in doc that :

> Important: This quickstart assumes that you have owner or editor roles
> in the project you are using for the quickstart. Otherwise, refer
> below for the permissions required information.
>
> [1](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-python-service#before-you-begin):  [Cloud Run deployment permissions](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/iam/roles#additional-configuration)
>
> A user needs the following permissions to deploy new Cloud Run
> services or revisions: run.services.create and run.services.update on
> the project level are required. run.services.get is not strictly
> required, but is recommended in order to read the status of the
> created service. Typically assigned through the roles/run.admin role.
>
> It can be changed in the project permissions admin page.
> iam.serviceAccounts.actAs for the Cloud Run runtime service account.
> By default, this is
> PROJECT_NUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com. The permission
> is typically assigned through the roles/iam.serviceAccountUser role.
>
> [2](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-python-service#deploy): [Cloud Build permissions](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/iam-roles-permissions#predefined_roles)
>
> With IAM, every API method in Cloud Build API requires that the
> identity making the API request has the appropriate permissions to use
> the resource.
>
> Permissions are granted by setting policies that grant
> roles to a principal (user, group, or service account). You can grant
> multiple roles to a principal on the same resource.
>
> [3](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/iam/roles#additional-configuration): [Artifact Registry permissions](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/access-control#permissions)
>
> Grant an Identity and Access Management (IAM) permission by granting a
> role that includes the permission. Use the Artifact Registry roles to
> control access to your repositories. You can grant permissions at the
> project or repository level.
>
> Although you can use the basic roles of
> Owner, Editor, and Viewer to grant access to repositories, using the
> Artifact Registry roles enables you to apply the security principle of
> least privilege, so that users and service accounts only have the
> permissions that are required.

you can refer to this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication#gcloud-helper) and make sure you have followed the mentioned 4 steps to authenticate to Artifact Registry.

If issue still persist,As I can see you already have created a [Public Issue tracker](https://b.corp.google.com/issues/249223258), we recommend to  [contact Google support and raise ticket](https://cloud.google.com/contact#:%7E:text=Get%20support%20for%20my%20current%20Google%20Cloud%20product%28s%29)  and provide the Project specific details so that the issue can resolves easily.

Comment: Hi Divyani Yadav, thanks for your reply. I still get the error message when adding permissions.

Comment: @My Car I have edited my answer can you check is it helpful by following these steps in doc [here](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/docker/authentication#gcloud-helper).

Comment: I created the key file, what should I replace with "KEY-FILE" in the command?

Comment: replace "Key-file" with json key file that you have created by help of this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating) .

Comment: What does "replace "Key-file" with json key file" mean, is it to replace "KEY-FILE" with the name of the json key file?

Comment: @MyCar yes , in the same way

Comment: Error replacing "KEY-FILE" with the name of the json key file: ERROR: (gcloud.auth.activate-service-account) Unable to read file [name-of-the-json-key-file]: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'name-of-the-json-key-file'

Comment: try to follow this [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67498627/15774176) or [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43047320/15774176) .

Comment: I don't get this error when using way 1.

Comment: I get the error: `ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) User [my-account] does not have permission to access projects instance [project-id] (or it may not exist): Permission 'run.locations.list' denied on resource 'projects/project-id' (or resource may not exist).`.

Comment: try to see this [1](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#deleted-default-service-account) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62783880/15774176), have you missed service account?

Comment: I solved this problem by adding "Cloud Run Admin" role.

Comment: But I get another error: `ERROR: (gcloud.run.deploy) The user is forbidden from accessing the bucket [project-id_cloudbuild]. Please check your organization's policy or if the user has the "serviceusage.services.use" permission`

Comment: How can I fix this error? I can't find a solution for now.

Comment: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70886335/15774176) once.

Comment: I get the first error again, `denied: Permission "artifactregistry.repositories.downloadArtifacts" denied on resource`.

Comment: let me reproduce this issue once will revert bak to you, try to see the documentation its due to the permission

Comment: Hi Divyani Yadav, is there any progress?

Comment: @MyCar hey, I reproduced the issue and i am able to deploy the service successfully.have you tried again ?and what error you got recently?

Comment: I try to add some roles to IAM account. I edited and displayed the role of the IAM account 2 hours ago, but the error persists

Comment: error message is same as mentioned in the question?

Comment: Yes, you are right

Comment: sure,let me check IAM roles mentioned in the questions once.